# PBKDF2 with HMAC in Java

Tags: passwords, java, password-policy, pbkdf2, hmac

I am working on a Java project where I must ensure the confidentiality and integrity of users password saved in a plaintext file.

To do so, I will write only a hash of the password in the file. More specifically, my intention is to write the hash of the password and a random salt, plus the random salt itself, to avoid the use of rainbow and lookup tables. I also want to use key-stretching with PBKDF2, to make the computation of the hash computationally expensive. 
Finally, I would like to use a keyed hash algorithm, HMAC, for a final layer of protection.

I am trying to implement my thoughts in a Java code, and I have found some examples of the operations that I have presented above:

```
private static byte[] pbkdf2(char[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int bytes)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, bytes * 8);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    return skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
}
```

The thing that I really cannot understand is how to input my secret key as the key used by the HMAC algorithm, as it doesn't seem an input to the function. I have looked through the Java documentation, but I cannot find a solution to my question.

At this point, I am not really sure if I understood correctly how the different part of the encryption mechanism work, so I would accept any help on the topic.

Comment: Just use Jasypt http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-passwords.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I see the confusion. You're apparently expecting your code to apply PBKDF2 then HMAC-SHA-1. That's not how it works: HMAC-SHA-1 is used inside PBKDF2.

The gist of [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) is to apply a function repeatedly which has the following properties:

- it takes two arguments;
- it returns a fixed-size value;
- it is practically undistinguishable from a pseudo-random function.

HMAC-SHA-1 is such a function, and a common choice. There are other variants of PBKDF2, using HMAC-MD5, HMAC-SHA-256, or other functions (but these variants aren't in the basic Java library).

PBKDF2 takes two data inputs (plus some configuration inputs): the password, and a salt. If you want to include a secret value in the calculation, PBKDF2's input is the place for it: don't tack on a custom scheme on top of that (doing your own crypto is a recipe for doing it wrong). Append the [pepper](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41754/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-pepper) (secret value common to all accounts) to the salt (public value that varies between accounts).

Note that [pepper is of limited usefulness](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough). It's only useful if the hashes and the pepper secret value are stored in different places — for example, if the hashes are in a database and the pepper is in a disk file that is not directly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.